# How to stop Android webview changing size when off the right or bottom of the screen

Tags: android, webview

I have a webview which is animated across the screen from left to right by updating its layout params.
eg:

```
x = x+10;
layoutP.rightMargin = x
WebView.setLayoutParams(layoutP);
```

And this seems to work fine moving the whole webview accross the screen

However when the webview reaches the the right (or bottom) edge  of the screen the view seems to resize it self to fit on screen (calling onSizeChanged)

So if the view width is set to 100 and the screen width is 200 when the view is at x=150 the view onSizeChanged is called with a width of 50, when I want it to remain 100.
The result is the webview tries to re-layout its content wrapping text when I dont want it to.

Does anyone have any ideas of how to fix this issue?

Thanks

Edit: Adding layout details
All the layouts are in code:

The parent layout:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams( LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT );
_layout = new RelativeLayout( _Activity );
```

The webview layout:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams pp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(100,100));
pp.leftMargin =  0;
pp.topMargin = 0;
_layout.addView( wV, pp);
```

And for what its worth these are the webview settings:

```
    setScrollContainer(false);
    setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

    setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    setHorizontalScrollbarOverlay(false);
    setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    setVerticalScrollbarOverlay(false);

    WebSettings ws = getSettings();
    ws.setSupportZoom(false);
    ws.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    ws.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    ws.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);

    if (Core.getAndroidAPIVersion() >= 8)
    {   
        ws.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    }
    else
    {
        ws.setPluginsEnabled(true);
    }

    ws.setAllowFileAccess(true);
    if (Core.getAndroidAPIVersion() >= 16) {
        ws.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    }
```

Comment: What are the initial width and height in the layout parameters? What layout is the WebView located in? Can you paste your layout XML code?

Comment: Need to see the LayoutParams for the WebView too.